# Count of distinct groups that have a value of > 0 in any of its records for a given column

Tags: sql, t-sql

The two columns:

A) company name.  There can be multiple records for a company: 1 record per company per month.

B) Sales.  For a given company for a given month, sales is a value 0 or greater.

What I want my query to return:

A count of all the **distinct companies** that had a sales of > 0 for **one or more months**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Simply translate text to SQL. You've already said it.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a novice, I attempted to do this but I'm dealing with a large data set and I'm not sure my results are correct.  Do you mind showing me this query?

Comment: @JesseDowning:please look here on how to improve the question as well:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to:

```
select count(distinct companyid)
from salestable
where sales > 0
```

Simply count the number of distinct companyid's who have a sales > 0.